# Visualize the call graph output of trace-cmd

Tags: ftrace, flamegraph

I am interested to learn about KVM. I started `trace-cmd` as follows:

```
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -g kvm_vcpu_ioctl -o nofuncgraph-irqs qemu-system-x86_64 ***
```

I analyzed the output file using Kernelshark. It is my first time using it, so I might not know how to use it properly. Anyway I found it hard to find the start and end of function calls.

What I am interested in is something like seeing the functions either as a flamegraph, but I am not interested at timing at all, I am only interested in hierarchy. Or seeing it in a way similar to an IDE where I can collapse those block of functions that I am not interested in.

Is there a way to generate a flamegraph out of the trace-cmd output or a tool to help with visualizing the call graph that is generated?